# How does a thread acquire a mutex lock?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

My question here is about a thread acquiring a mutex lock.

We use `pthread_mutex_t` locks to ensure sequential access to variables, when being read/written in a multi-threaded program. But `pthread_mutex_t lock ;` is also a global variable shared between threads. Will accessing of *this* global variable (the lock) be the same as accessing other global variables? If it is the same, then won't we face the *same* problem that we will face for other global variables? And if not, then how accessing a lock data structure different from accessing other global variables?

In short: Why don't we need to lock access to locks themselves and so end up in a chicken-and-egg problem?

Comment: In which language? Pre-C11 the language doesn't have a notion of "threads", so the question doesn't exist. In C11 you would say that calls of `pthread_mutex_lock` synchronize with one another without specifying details of how this happens. And if you want to build locks yourself, you can use atomic variables as fundamental building blocks which offer synchronizing access.

Comment: In c language , linux OS.

Comment: @KerrekSB pthread has been specified by the POSIX standard for quite some time. I don't see why the C standard version matters when you are using the pthread library anyhow.

Comment: @Lundin Have you read the article “threads cannot be implemented as a library”? http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2004/HPL-2004-209.pdf

Comment: @PascalCuoq No, but the fact is that they have been implemented in that way since the mid 90s or so, correct or not correct.

Comment: @PascalCuoq: it was never a pure library. it has heavy compiler support.

Comment: I think the atomicity guarantee is up to the OS, pthread is only an abstraction library. Of course if the OS does no guarantee the mutex atomic state, your threads have a big problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "the same as accessing of global variables"? What is "the same problem that we will face for other global variables"? What are you asking? About race conditions?

Comment: Have a look at the NTPL in libc, e.g. https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob_plain;f=nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c;hb=HEAD and others. Long story short: libc uses atomic exchange operations and other magic.

Comment: @JonathanWakely I believe the question is: *We need to use locks to ensure sequential access to data. But what do we use to ensure sequential access to the lock data structure itself?*

Comment: OK, then the answer is you do nothing, operations on mutexes are implicitly serialized, using atomic operations and memory fences, or kernel-based synchronisation primitives that cannot be interrupted by other threads. **Obviously** mutexes have to be special in some way, or they just wouldn't work.

Comment: @BheemeshAgasi Just a note. I have edited your question to be (hopefully) more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really access `pthread_mutex_t` variables directly, you access them with some given functions (`pthread_mutex_lock` for example).

These functions are built so that there is no concurrent access to these structures, either by the use of some test-and-set instruction (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-and-set) or by using some atomic portion of code (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability).